# IGBT driver IC TCC4421 getting hot when connected to IGBT gate through a toroidal transformer

Tags: pwm, h-bridge, igbt

A strange overheating problem:

A TL494 PWM controller pulsating a TC4421 buffer IC, which is connected through a series 0.47uf capacitor to the primary of a toroidal transformer.  The secondary is connected to the IGBT gate via a 10R resistor. The IGBT is off, no high voltage connected to collector, yet the IC gets too hot to touch.

Does anyone know why the driving IC is heating up? When I connect the secondary to a power MOSFET, no heating happens.

Comment: What happens to the pwm? You need to take some measurements otherwise it’s all guesswork. My guess is the toroid saturates.

Comment: Schematic along with transformer specs and oscillogram is needed to answer it but I agree with Kartman, probably transformer saturation.